# При первом открытии дизайнера win forms, появляется белый экран

Tags: winforms, visual-studio

Когда перехожу с другого элемента или вкладки в Visual Studio, на форму, появляется белый экран, после переоткрытия работает корректно. Подскажите в чем может быть причина?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]